# Python rolling slope

Tags: python, linear-regression, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with several columns. I would like to append a new column with the slope of the best fit line of a linear regression of the previous 5 rows. One dataframe column as the independent variable and another column as the dependent variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"B":[5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 6.5, 7, 8.5, 8, 9, 10, 10.5],  
                   "C":[22, 23.5, 23, 24, 23.5, 24, 24.25, 25, 25.7, 27, 26.5]})
```

I've tried a number of things like sklearn.linear_model. I can easily find and define that slope for the entire dataframe. But I am struggling to define the frame to be evaluated for every row and iterating that for every row through the entire dataframe

[Original Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpo88.jpg)
[New Dataframe after appended column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAKaO.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? Also you should add dataframe data instead of a picture so that it is possible to reproduce them.

Comment: Yes, add a sample please

Comment: Hi and Welcome, please read [ask].